# WCF Service Max number of Methods

Tags: wcf, web-services

What is the maximum number of methods/operations that can be exposed via a single WCF Service Contract?

Answer (score 7):

Although there is no maximum, you may run into issues with `Metadata Exchange` - and the following config value and it's default: `maxNameTableCharCount`.

Whilst attempting to add a new function to an existing functioning `WCF Service`, I encountered errors whilst trying to "*Update Service Reference*" - relating to default value of `maxNameTableCharCount` being too small to handle the size of the `mex` transfer.

It is possible to override the default values for `Metadata Exchange` by adding a custom `mex binding` within the server config.

You may see an error message like below when you try to add or update your service reference if the config value is exceeded:

> The maximum nametable character count quota (16384) has been exceeded
>   while reading XML data. The nametable is a data structure used to
>   store strings encountered during XML processing - long XML documents
>   with non-repeating element names, attribute names and attribute values
>   may trigger this quota. This quota may be increased by changing the
>   MaxNameTableCharCount property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object
>   used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 332845.

Server Mex endpoints should be specified as follows:

```
<endpoint address="mex" 
          binding="customBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange" 
          name="" 
          bindingConfiguration="customMex" 
          listenUriMode="Explicit" />
```

With a Custom Binding block specified as follows:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="customMex">
        <textMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </textMessageEncoding>
        <httpTransport transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                       maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

It may help if you're running into issues with lots of methods on a service.

Comment: `mex` is used by the WCF tools in order to generate a proxy class for the client, but is never really used by the client itself.  So why does the client config file need this binding added?

Comment: You're quite right, the client config doesn't require any corresponding config. I have modified the post now, thanks.

Comment: I have not had any success following this method.  I am using netTcp binding for my service.  I have http disabled, and so I have specified tcpTransport instead of httpTransport.  But this still fails when I have a large number of OperationContracts.  Can anyone provide any input?

Comment: How do you do this type of thing programmatically?

Comment: @Alexandru what type of thing exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @Tanner How you set the reader quotas in the XAML, I'm wondering how you would do this to a programmatic binding created in C#...

Comment: @Alexandru this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969479/modify-endpoint-readerquotas-programatically

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum.  You can have as many as you wish, AFAIK.

However, whether or not it is practical is a different issue.  It will become quite unwieldy if you have too many methods on a single contract.

Answer (score 0):

The practical limit is probably no more than 10-12 methods.  Any more than that and you're probably no longer describing the operations of a single component.  I'd try really hard to refactor any component with dozens of operations down into multiple components.

That said, I'm sure there are exceptions!