# Modify endpoint ReaderQuotas programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf, readerquotas

I have a dynamic client to a service. How can i change the ReaderQuotas property of it's endpoint binding?

I tried like this but it doesn't work ...

```
 DynamicProxyFactory factory = new DynamicProxyFactory(m_serviceWsdlUri);

 foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in factory.Endpoints)
 {
     Binding binding =  endpoint.Binding;

     binding.GetProperty<XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas>(new BindingParameterCollection()).MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
     binding.GetProperty<XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas>(new BindingParameterCollection()).MaxBytesPerRead =2147483647;
     binding.GetProperty<XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas>(new BindingParameterCollection()).MaxDepth = 2147483647;
     binding.GetProperty<XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas>(new BindingParameterCollection()).MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
     binding.GetProperty<XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas>(new BindingParameterCollection()).MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
   }
```

Even after doing this the ReaderQuotas values remain the default ones.

I also tried like this and still doesn't work:

```
     DynamicProxyFactory factory = new DynamicProxyFactory(m_serviceWsdlUri);

     foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in factory.Endpoints)
     {
         System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingElementCollection bec = endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();

         System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportBindingElement tbe = bec.Find<System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportBindingElement>();

         tbe.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
         tbe.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
         TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBE = bec.Find<TextMessageEncodingBindingElement>();

         if (textBE != null)
         {

             textBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
             textBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
             textBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
             textBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
             textBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;

         }
   }
```

I need this so I can send more than 8kb to the service.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Setting quotas on a BindingElement after the binding is created has no effect on that binding.

Edit (since you don't know what binding is used):

You can use reflection to set the property. Note you should make sure the Binding actually has the property before setting it. Not all bindings have this property. If you try to set it on a binding that doesn't support it, the example will throw an exception.

```
Binding binding = endpoint.Binding;

XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = _sanebutusablelimit_;
myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = _sanebutusablelimit_;
myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = _sanebutusablelimit_;
myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = _sanebutusablelimit_;
myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = _sanebutusablelimit_;

binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, myReaderQuotas, null);
```

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: +1 for mentioning these things have to be set BEFORE the client proxy and/or service host are created. Once created, they're immutable.

Comment: Hi Marc,
Thanks for the reply, but I don't know what kind of binding it is, that's why i need to do it after binding is created.
Any other suggestions?

Thanks, Adrya

Comment: What do you mean, you don't know what kind of binding it is.  In the ServiceHostFactory, just look in the binding and modify the quota if you need to.  If what you are saying is, you don't know you need to modify the quota until after you USE the binding, then ..maybe set a flag and then restart the host (or client proxy) .

Comment: I edited my reply to deal with unknown bindings by using reflection.

Comment: How can i set MaxReceivedMessageSize?

Answer (score 11):

Why are you solving that in a such complex way, just alter the ReaderQuotas directly:

ie:

WSHttpBinding WebBinding = new WSHttpBinding();

**WebBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
WebBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
WebBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;**

This will work without that weird reflection sample.

Cheers

Comment: Because client is dynamically created when it gets to my hands, so bindings and everything are already created, i just wanted to increase message size of that client.

Answer (score 1):

Also to be noted, is that the following properties of the Binding also need to be updated for the complete solution:

```
binding2.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
binding2.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
```

For the benefit of others here is a sample that programmatically sets the ReaderQuotas on both the client and the server along with the 2 properties above:

Client code:

```
        WebHttpBinding binding2 = new WebHttpBinding();
        XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;

        binding2.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding2, myReaderQuotas, null);
        binding2.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        binding2.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        ServiceEndpoint ep = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IMyService)),
            binding2, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9000/MyService"));

        WebChannelFactory<IMyService> cf2 = new WebChannelFactory<IMyService>(ep);

        IMyService serv = cf2.CreateChannel();
        serv.PrintNameDesc("Ram", new string('a', 100*1024*1024));
```

Server code:

```
        WebHttpBinding binding2 = new WebHttpBinding();
        XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;

        binding2.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding2, myReaderQuotas, null);
        binding2.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        binding2.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;

        WebServiceHost host2 = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
        host2.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding2, new Uri("http://localhost:9000/MyService"));

        host2.Open();
```

Where the contract is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", 
        UriTemplate = "My/{name}/", 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [OperationContract]
    void PrintNameDesc(string name, string desc);
}
```